# JQuery DataTables link item

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to link the items from a specific column, but each one will be linked for a different `id` from the json string. Unfortunately I can't find a way to do this using the API (I know there is a lot of ways to do that without using the API ), but I'm looking for a way to link a item from a column (each one with a link for a specific `id`).

So here is my code, I use `getJSON` to get the JSON from the server, and I load the data from this JSON to the table like this:

```
$.getJSON("http://url.from/method?parameter=foo&callback=?", function(data)
    {
        var total = 0;
        $("#table_body").empty();
        var oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable(
            {
                "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
                "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
            }); 

        oTable.fnClearTable();

        $.each(data, function(i, item) 
        {
            oTable.fnAddData(
                [
                    item.contact_name,
                    item.contact_email
                ]
            );
        });
    });
```

What I want to do, is for each row, link the `contact_name` to its `id`, which is also in the JSON, and can be accessed inside this `$.each` loop by using `item.contact_id`.

Is there a way to do this using DataTables API, if yes, could you explain me and provide a good resource that will help me with this?

**OBS: I'm using JSONP**

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE WITH MY NEW CODE:**

The error now is, I'm getting the id when I click, but due to the fact that I'm processing the rows inside the `$.each` loop, for any row I click, it will always get the `id` of the last processed row.

```
var options = 
        {
            "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
            "aoColumns": [{
                "sTitle": 'Name',
                "sClass": "dtName",
            }, {
                "sTitle": 'Email',
                "sClass": "dtEmail",
            }, {
                "bVisible": false
            }],
        }

        var oTable = $('#table').dataTable(options); // Creates a new instance of the DataTable

        oTable.fnClearTable();

        $.each(data, function(i, item) 
        {

            oTable.fnAddData(
                [
                    item.contact_name , 
                    item.contact_email,
                    item.contact_id
                ]
            );

            var rowData = oTable.fnGetData(i); // fetch all the ids into this array
            $('#table tbody tr').click( function() 
            {
                window.location.href = "/panel/contacts/"+rowData[2];
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
var options = {
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumns": [{
        "sTitle": 'Name',
        "sClass": "dtName",
    }, {
        "sTitle": 'Email',
        "sClass": "dtEmail",
    }, {
        "bVisible": false
    }],
}
var oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable(options);
```

This table **will not display the id column**, **but you can get it** like the following code:

```
var rowData = oTable.fnGetData(rowNode);
```

**or**

```
var rowData = oTable.fnGetData(0); // for the first one

console.log(rowData[0]);
```

You can't get it by jQuery because it's not displayed.

**Edited:** Sorry, I forgot one thing, when you use AddData put the item.contact_id on the third position:

```
oTable.fnAddData([
    item.contact_name,
    item.contact_email,
    item.contact_id
]);
```

If you want to get the id on click event do it:

```
jQuery('#mytable tbody tr').live('click', function() {
    var selectedRow = oTable.fnGetData(this),
        url = "/yourUrl/" + selectedRow[2];

    window.location.replace(url);
});
```

Comment: Wait.. Where is the JSON items in this code? I can see that you are loading some text and translating it, but where to you load (as I've shown in my code before) item.contact_name and item.contact_email?

Comment: So, you'll load on the same place, just modify your functions.

Comment: BTW it says en4 is not defined, maybe I need to load this libs somewhere, where can I find it? And in my HTML code, I didn't declare the <tbody> tag, due to the fact that it will be generated by fnAddData. Correct?

Comment: @rogcg No no, forget my en4.translate it's what I use to translate my js strings, I put it wrong, sorry.

Comment: OK, now I'm getting the contact_id. But, it doesn't store the old id's loaded. So in the end, for every row I click, it will be always the id of the last row added. How to I get the id of the current row I'm clicking to?

Comment: Save it into a var and then concat with your url like: var rowData = oTable.fnGetData(0); var url = '/anotherpage/' + rowData[0];

Comment: Yeah, but its not getting the id of the row I'm clicking, it always get the id of the last row processed. I'm gonna post an update with my new code.

Comment: I updated my answer with the code to get the row id and redirect the page.

Comment: Now if you want to do something when user clicks the row you can do on jquery click event.